# Is there a max allowance for entries in a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is there a set maximum (or even a recommended maximum) for how many entries that can/should be stored in a mysql table? How much is really too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to set the maximum number of rows on a table for MyISAM.

According to the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) under `AVG_ROW_LENGTH`:

> When you create a MyISAM table, MySQL uses the product of the MAX_ROWS
>   and AVG_ROW_LENGTH options to decide how big the resulting table is.
>   If you don't specify either option, the maximum size for MyISAM data
>   and index files is 256TB by default. (If your operating system does
>   not support files that large, table sizes are constrained by the file
>   size limit.) If you want to keep down the pointer sizes to make the
>   index smaller and faster and you don't really need big files, you can
>   decrease the default pointer size by setting the
>   myisam_data_pointer_size system variable. (See Section 5.1.3, “Server
>   System Variables”.) If you want all your tables to be able to grow
>   above the default limit and are willing to have your tables slightly
>   slower and larger than necessary, you can increase the default pointer
>   size by setting this variable. Setting the value to 7 permits table
>   sizes up to 65,536TB.

According to the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) under `MAX_ROWS`:

> MAX_ROWS   The maximum number of rows you plan to store in the table.
>   This is not a hard limit, but rather a hint to the storage engine that
>   the table must be able to store at least this many rows.
>
> The NDB storage engine treats this value as a maxmimum. If you plan to
>   create very large MySQL Cluster tables (containing millions of rows),
>   you should use this option to insure that NDB allocates sufficient
>   number of index slots in the hash table used for storing hashes of the
>   table's primary keys by setting MAX_ROWS = 2 * rows, where rows is the
>   number of rows that you expect to insert into the table.
>
> Note   This option was incorrectly ignored by MySQL Cluster NDB 7.0
>   prior to version 7.0.20 and MySQL Cluster NDB 7.1 prior to version
>   7.1.9 (see Bug #57360).
>
> The maximum MAX_ROWS value is 4294967295; larger values are truncated
>   to this limit.

In terms of the number of columns, InnoDB  cannot support more than 1000 columns, while MyISAM can support more.

For further comparison, please read the MySQL Documentation on [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) and [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) for their limits and options to change any configurable limits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's amazing to fathom that someone could actually have 42 billion entries in a table... and what kind of hardware is required to query a table of that magnitude. I'm still in the minors and work as a computer tech, coder, ... I suppose a general I.T. employee for a small corporation, but I am interested in developing enterprise applications.

Comment: I used to run a system with one particular table of over 4.5 billion rows, and depending on the filtering of the query, if it matched the index nicely, it would return results in < 10 seconds at times. The table was 200Gb (inc indexes), and ran on an Intel dual quad core with 64Gb ram, and the data was on a 14 disk RAID 10 array... so it is doable!!! :)

Comment: So you mean *MyISAM* is a better engine than *InnoDB* for huge dataset? *(something like 5 milliard of rows)*

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at MySQL documentation and there seems to be **no maximum number** for records in a table, but taking a look at MySQL [features](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/features.html) page:

> Scalability and Limits:
>
> Support for large databases. We use MySQL Server with databases that
>   contain 50 million records. We also know of users who use MySQL Server
>   with 200,000 tables and about 5,000,000,000 rows.
>
> Support for up to 64 indexes per table (32 before MySQL 4.1.2). Each
>   index may consist of 1 to 16 columns or parts of columns. The maximum
>   index width is 1000 bytes (767 for InnoDB); before MySQL 4.1.2, the
>   limit is 500 bytes. An index may use a prefix of a column for CHAR,
>   VARCHAR, BLOB, or TEXT column types.

According to this information, the recommended maximum number of records may vary a lot depending on your hardware limitations but would probably be around the boundaries of **5,000,000,000 rows**.

EXTRA: if you plan to store really large numbers of records in a table, care to use the [MAX_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) parameter in your `CREATE TABLE` data definition statements.